Project files via p4 have the wrong line endings
for an unknown reason the files I have downloaded via p4 have the wrong line endings (UNIX, I need Win) and won't compile in VS.
I have tried changing the line endings setting in "edit current workspace" and re-getting latest but it doesn't get the files in question. Is there a setting I can change and re-get the files that have the wrong LE and not have to re-get the entire project again? Thanks

Check your client/workspace for the proper line ending. Then a forced sync will freshen everything up: https://www.perforce.com/manuals/cmdref/Content/CmdRef/p4_client.html#Processi

After you've fixed your LineEnd setting (you almost always want this to be local; in very rare cases you might want share but that usually involves filesystems that are directly shared between Windows and Unix systems), you should assume that every text file in your workspace needs to be re-synced.
If most of the files in your workspace are text, just do p4 sync -f, but if you want to specifically only sync the text files (maybe you have lots of large binary files you want to avoid re-downloading), you can do a query with p4 fstat and pipe it to p4 sync like this:
C:\Perforce\test\types>p4 files ...
//stream/main/types/bar.jpg#1 - add change 514 (binary)
//stream/main/types/foo.txt#1 - add change 514 (text)

C:\Perforce\test\types>p4 -F %depotFile% fstat -F headType=text ... | p4 -x - sync -f
//stream/main/types/foo.txt#1 - refreshing c:\Perforce\test\types\foo.txt

Note that files with the type binary will not have any line ending conversion performed on them; if you have some files that should always have a particular line ending convention regardless of what workspace they're synced to, consider using the binary filetype for those.
